# Android - Java if (a OR b)?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know how to express `OR` in `Java`. I always thought it was `||`. But this does not work in my `Android` App.

So e.g here:

```
if (team1.getText() **"OR"?** team2.getText() == "myteam");
```

How can I set the `OR` statement?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? The logical OR operator in java is indeed `||`.

Comment: Are you comparing strings? If so, use the mystring.equals() method.

Comment: it says the operator|| is undefined

Comment: Shouldn't you add the toString() method to it as well, right now your comparing a CharSequence to a String, don't think it would matter to much tho

Comment: @SmartLemon It's not a CharSequence to my knowledge, rather a string literal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`if("myteam".equals(team1.getText()) || "myteam".equals(team2.getText()))`

You cannot do something like `if((foo || bar).equals(anotherString))`.

Comment: I would suspect another huge cause of confusion is == vs ".equals()"

Answer (score 2):

A couple of this might be causing the problem. `if(team1.getText())` will break, as it is not a boolean statement, so you cannot use the `||` operator on it.

The other problem is your method of comparing strings. Strings in java are not comparable with the == operator, because that is trying to compare the location in memory of a two String objects or literals, or a mix, and that will not return true unless they are the same instance of a String.

You have to compare strings with the `equals()` method on a String object or a string literal.

Comment: I sure hope `if(nonBooleanStatement)` doesn't return `true`. It shouldn't even compile.